# Java CSV data String array to double

Tags: java, csv

Hi i have a CSV file with 2 column, i can read the data and i did split it for 2 part `String[] country = line.split(";");`, i did split `country[1]` `String[] price_split = country[1].split(" ");` and got 2 part, the first part is (yes i know that all item is string)(first item a string and the other 4 item is double), i want to convert the 4 double from price_split[0] to 4 distinct double
my code is

```
String csvFile = "pontcsoport.csv";
BufferedReader br = null;
String line = "";

try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

        String[] country = line.split(";");

                    String[] price_split = country[1].split(" ");
                    System.out.println(price_split[0]);

    }

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (br != null) {
        try {
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

System.out.println("Done");
```

and the output is:

```
price
70.99
21.38
19.24
12.83
Done
```

So i want that `double a=70.99; double b=21.38;` etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to convert `String` to `Double` use,

```
String str = "12.00";
double d = Double.parseDouble(str);
```

If you want to store the details as `Double` format create a list with `Double` & store accordingly.

```
List<Double> doubleDTList = new ArrayList<Double>();

 while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

     // Other Stuff's
     System.out.println(price_split[0]);
     try{
          doubleDTList.add(Double.parseDouble(price_split[0]));
     } catch(NumberFormatException e){
     }

}
```

And this `doubleDTList` contains all the values.

Comment: I know how to convert string to double, the problem that my String array have 5 item and i cant separate them to 5 distinct part, as u see in my output, price_split have 2 part (0,1) and i want the part 0 to 5 distinct part

Comment: It will be good but the first item is a String :( so doubleDTList first item will be "price"

Comment: @user5555231 edited accordingly. if string came NFE cause and will not add to the list.

Comment: I tried and test with System.out.println(doubleDTList.get(1)); but i got error: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0
so there is no element in doubleDTList :(

Comment: @user5555231 where u print this inside while loop or outside ? Please it print outside. And (doubleDTList.get(1)) will give the 2nd element. Toget first u need to print it with index as 0.

Comment: Oh, i f*cked up, its working :) BIG thanks for you :)